# What happened to the Journal of Justice?

Tags: league-of-legends

The last one was released in July 2011 and I loved to read them. I thought the stories were in depth and you got to learn about a lot of the champions. Was there any information given on why they stopped producing them?

Comment: @Brant Well, in this case, there was an official explanation. A little editing and it'll work.

Comment: What is the best way I could edit this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riot decided that the Journal of Justice (as well as the Judgement for Individual Champions)  was not the best way to present future League of Legends lore. There are two outstanding issues of the Journal of Justice slated for the near-future, after which it will stop entirely.

> We have been examining the best way to do this and are still in the
>   process of doing so. However, in the mean time, we will no longer be
>   releasing Judgments. We need to take the time we put into those pieces
>   of fiction and apply it towards finding a better solution. We will be
>   concluding the in-progress storylines and completing the Journal of
>   Justice over two issues, as soon as we spin up the required art
>   resources.
>
> We should have a clearer picture of what will fill these Lore vacuums
>   over the coming months and will keep you updated. Thank you for caring
>   about the Lore behind League of Legends. We promise that what comes
>   next will satisfy!

[Source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1680645)